# Markers for feminine and masculine names in Old Norse?

Tags: old-norse, onomastics

A question in two parts:

One, is there a way, other than original context, to determine whether a name in Old Norse is generally masculine or generally feminine?

Two, how would one go about feminizing a masculine name (or vice versa) in Old Norse? My particular interest in this case is the god name Mundilfäri, used for a male god; what would the feminine form of it be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Sadly, Old Norse gender can't readily be seen just by the suffix.

   Male nouns generally end:

   - in -r, -ll or -nn if strong (e.g. *Baldr*, *Heimdall* and *Óðinn*)
   - and in -i when weak (e.g. *Loki*).

   Female nouns

   - take no suffix (but umlaut) when strong (e.g. *Sjöfn*)
   - and end in -a when weak (e.g. *Freyja*).

   **However**, there are a few female nouns (and names) that end with -r or -i, e.g. *Urðr*. Also, there are male names that look (and are declined) like female nouns, e.g. *Sturla*. As a rule of thumb, a male noun will always have a suffix, whereas a female one needn't, but as the Sturla example shows, that doesn't straightforwardly carry over to names.
2. I can't find any good etymology for the -föri or -fari or -färi in Mundilföri, which makes it hard to correctly predict all the sound changes you might have to do or undo to get a corresponding female form; also, a female form might just not exist since -färi might well be a male noun without a corresponding female one. People seem to think that it comes from *fara*, to go or travel, but I am not aware of a way of forming a nomen agentis in Old Norse with -i. Also, I don't know whether or not the Umlaut was derived via i-umlaut. With all these caveats, anything you do is guessing anyways, so you can pick the one you like best:

   - **Mundilfara** (replace male weak -i by female weak -a and undo possible umlaut)
   - **Mundilfära** (or -föra) if you'd like to keep the umlaut
   - **Mundilför** (or -fär(?) (I can't remember the letter ä in standardized Old Icelandic) for a strong female ending.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I'll need to hunt down an Old Norse grammar, I think, for a better understanding of the division between strong and weak nouns.

Comment: @plagueheart Strong and weak are just two "super"-paradigms for declining a noun, the strong ones having more distinct case endings. There is no semantic difference, it's just like some verbs have different ways of forming the past in English.

Comment: Oh, duh, right. Sorry, as is probably obvious from my relatively inept phrasing in my question, I'm only passing familiar with the actual terminology of linguistics. I'm sure I've encountered strong/weak nouns in discussion of declension patterns, it just didn't stick in my head.

Comment: It's no trouble at all. Strong/weak is, as far as I'm aware, a distinction generally (and only) made in Germanic languages. In English, strong verbs are irregular verbs like sing - sang - sung, while the boring ones (talk - talked - talked) are weak. It doesn't really bear on your question at all, I just used the strong/weak distinction to organise my answer.

Comment: it's worth noting that the two strong/weak distinctions don't have anything to do with each other. English umlaut plurals (e.g. foot/feet) are actually weak nouns from a specific neuter paradigm, despite involving vowel changes which might make you think they ought to be strong by comparison with the distinction in verbs

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the comprehensive answer above (I don't have enough reputation to comment), feminine names also often end in *-un(n)*.

Some examples taken from the sagas and Norse mythology are Guðrún, Þorunn, and Iðunn.

Here is a list of names taken from early Icelandic written source: [http://www.ellipsis.cx/~liana/names/norse/landnamabok.html](http://www.ellipsis.cx/%7Eliana/names/norse/landnamabok.html). See the section "Feminine Names" for some more examples.

Note that the declension pattern for these nouns is different than for standard strong feminine nouns, with a vowel stem (*u/i*) manifesting in the oblique cases:

| Nom | Guðrún | Þórunn | Iðunn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acc | Guðrúnu | Þórunni | Iðunni |
| Dat | Guðrúnu | Þórunni | Iðunni |
| Gen | Guðrúnar | Þórunnar | Iðunnar |

Comment: Could you add some more detail, like examples, or an explanation of where this comes from, or how these names decline? As it is this is a valid answer, but a rather short one.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestion.